# php google maps for website API javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm trying to get the google maps for websites API working on my php website.
for that I have a php page that loads users variables for the maps.
the javascript  works fine in the webpage with default values, but I'm not able to load the $php variable into the script.

maybe some javascript expert can give a hand

```
function onProfileDisplay() {
            $user           = CFactory::getRequestUser();
            $document       =& JFactory::getDocument();
            $document->addStyleSheet($css);
            $my         = CFactory::getUser();
            $pluginParams = $this->params;
            $param = new stdClass;
            $param = $Lat = $pluginParams->get('Lat');
            $param = $Lng = $pluginParams->get('Lng');
            $param = $width = $pluginParams->get('width');
            $param = $height = $pluginParams->get('height');
            $param = $zoom = $pluginParams->get('zoom');
            return '<body onload="onprofileDisplay()">  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:500px"></div>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

 function onProfileDisplay() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
            **var zoom = <?php echo ($zoom) ?>;**
            var settings = {
                    **zoom: zoom,**
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
            var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
            var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: companyPos,
            map: map,
            title:"Some title"
            });
            }
            </script>
                    ';
            }
```

to test I'm only trying to load the php variable $zoom into the javascript, but it does not work,
inside the javascript:

```
var zoom = <?php echo ($zoom) ?>;
zoom: zoom,
```

but it does not work, if I change the javascript to original
remove var     zoom = ;
    zoom: 15,
then it works but with static default values

Help appreciated.

**This is the outuput code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onProfileDisplay() { 
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
    var zoom = ".$zoom.";
            var settings = {
                    ".$zoom.":".$zoom.",
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {style:   google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                    navigationControl: true,
                    navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
            var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
            var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: companyPos,
            map: map,
            });
            }
    </script>
```

The original code looks like:

```
     public function onProfileDisplay() {
                $user           = CFactory::getRequestUser();
                $document       =& JFactory::getDocument();
                $document->addStyleSheet($css);
                $my         = CFactory::getUser();
                $pluginParams = $this->params;
                $param = new stdClass;
                $param = $api_key = $pluginParams->get('api_key');
                $param = $Lat = $pluginParams->get('Lat');
                $param = $Lng = $pluginParams->get('Lng');
                $param = $width = $pluginParams->get('width');
                $param = $height = $pluginParams->get('height');
                $param = $zoom = $pluginParams->get('zoom');
                 return  '<body onload="onProfileDisplay()">
                        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:800px; height:500px"></div
</body>
                        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                function onProfileDisplay() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
                var zoom = ".$zoom.";
                var settings = {
                        ".$zoom.":".$zoom.",
                        center: latlng,
                        mapTypeControl: true,
                        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
                        navigationControl: true,
                        navigationControlOptions: {style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL},
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);
                var companyPos = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
                var companyMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: companyPos,
                map: map,
                });
                }
                </script>';
                }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you putting PHP into the return from PHP->javascript function? Seems like a v cumbersome way to get your result.

In any event - why not just put the actual values in there from the PHP function? Once they are in javascript on the client you won't be able to use the server-side value anyway.

example:

> function onProfileDisplay() {
>               var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.0442, 9.9116);
>               var zoom = " . $zoom . "
>               var settings = {
>                       " . $zoom . ":" . $zoom . ",
>                       center: latlng,

Comment: thanks for the help, the script works but the zoom value is not coming from the php, I tested it with document.write(zoom); and the output is $zoom, not the php value for the variable $zoom

Comment: `code`var zoom = " .$zoom. ";
                var settings = {
                        " .$zoom. ": " .$zoom. ",
                        center: latlng,`code` you change actually do not breack the script and the google maps layer shows up blank, because the value being passed for zoom is $zoom and not the php variable

Comment: Do a 'view source' on the output and put it in the question

Comment: I saved the page, opened it from hard disk and control+U, the output is in the original question. Thanks

Comment: change this: var zoom = ".$zoom.";
                var settings = {
                        ".$zoom.":".$zoom.",   to this: var zoom = '.$zoom.';
                var settings = {
                        '.$zoom.':'.$zoom.',

Comment: I check the output and var was getting me the value ....... iupi, but var settings = { '.$zoom.':'.$zoom.', needed to be changed to zoom:'.$zoom.', and it works... YOU ARE THE MAN.... Thanks.